# Swift cannot use found values out of reverseGeocodeLocation()

Tags: swift, location, geocode

I tried to store the city found by the reverseGeocodeLocation method inside a variable but it seems that it's not possible with the following code to reuse it inside a variable decelerated before. Debugger showed me that a city is found and is stored inside returnCity but only during execution of the reverseGeocodeLocation method.

I found some other posts but none of them helped me with my problem.

Thank you for any help!

```
    // Get City out of coordinates
    var returnCity = ""
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: self.selectedLat, longitude: self.selectedLng)
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        // Place details
        var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
        placeMark = placemarks?[0]

        // City
        if let foundCity = placeMark.locality {
            returnCity = foundCity
        }
    })
    NSLog("Sub Locality is: " + returnCity) // console shows "Sub Locality is: "
```

Comment: Put your `NSLog` inside `completionHandler`

Comment: Yes then it is displayed but I would like to use the value outside of the method, that's why I created the returnCity String?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use property observer to update your UI or use the updated result. I would modify "returnCity" property like below and use the data as soon as it is set and every time it is changed inside a didSet observer.

```
  var returnCity:String?  {
        didSet {
            guard let returnCity = self.returnCity else {return}
               NSLog("Sub Locality is: " + returnCity)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, unfortunately it tells me "Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'returnCity'" on line 3

Comment: Did you try to build the project? It’s seems to be a compiler issue because if you declared a property then you shouldn’t get that error. Simply try to build and see if it won’t work.

Comment: Build failed even after I cleaned build folder :/

Comment: Then it must be a minor in your code , var returnCity should be declared inside a ViewController. You are getting that error because the compiler can’t find “returnCity” property. Can you edit your question to include more details on how your whole viewController code look like?

Comment: Ok so If I declare this with my other variables it works but then I still can only use the value inside of this didSet method. Isn't there any way to use it outside of it?

Comment: Just make a function outside and call it inside didSet, it’s a value fetched from remote server and that’s the best way to work with such values.